# gcc is recognized by cmd, but not by bash

Tags: windows, bash, ubuntu

I'm using windows sub-system for linux, installed ubuntu, and bash is running smoothly.
I'm trying to use make, and it seems that bash doesn't recognize gcc. Tried adding it to PATH, but nothing changed. The weird thing is - cmd **does** recognize gcc.

Do I need to install it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to install gcc to the Ubuntu Sybsystem for Windows?

```
sudo apt install gcc
```

Comment: No, that's why I opened the thread, becuase I was wondering if it's a matter of bash not recognizing gcc because of PATH or some other thing; or do I really need to install gcc again

Comment: Do you had gcc on windows before installing Ubuntu WSL? If yes then you would need to install gcc on your Ubuntu enviroment.
I mean you can't use your windows gcc on ubuntu without installing it first there if that's what you mean.

Comment: That answers it perfectly, thank ya!